# No access to phpmyadmin in EasyPHP

Tags: phpmyadmin, easyphp

I just reinstalled EasyPHP as my old installation just went corrupt. After the new installation I cannot get access to phpmyadmin. When pressing the link in the administration panel to go to the module nothing happens. It starts loading the module URL but no result or timeout oor even error message. I therefore installed the newest phpmyadmin module, but the same issue arises. There is no change to the standard setup and no password set.

I also tried to install the module Virtual Host in order to try and access it through     `http://phpmyadmin` but there I get this error `Unfortunately, you do not have rights to create a Virtual Host. You must have write permissions on the file: C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.` I tried but am not allowed to change the permissions to the file.

I'm also wondering whether there could be som issue with my firewall but nothing changes if I disable it.

Can anybody please help?
I don't know what more to try, and the EasyPHP site doesn't seem to give me answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have administrator privileges to edit `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. If it's your PC just login as administrator and add user you use to normal work on your PC, full privileges to this file.

Otherwise you need to contact system administrator and ask him to add entries you want into `hosts` file.

There is no other way - only administator or person with full rights can edit `hosts` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can edit the file as administrator by opening the file in Notepad -> Run as administrator. Can you tell me what to put in the file to make it work?

Comment: So far I worked around the problem by disabling the AVG which creates the problem. When AVG is disabled then it works. I did already add exceptions to the paths and files for phpMyAdmin, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are administrator on Windows 7, you can try to close and reopen EasyPhp with admin privilege (right-click on EasyPhp exe, run as administrator).

Answer (score -1):

Actually the best way to edit this file and get around Windows annoying admin stuff is to move the file to the desktop, do your edits, save it, then drag it back into the original folder.